# Firebase function SequelizeConnectionError while connecting to AWS RDS

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

Firebase function cannot connect to AWS RDS. I'm using Sequelize ORM to connect to the DB. In my local it is working fine but when I deploy to firebase functions, it is giving ERROR: SequelizeConnectError: connect ETIMEOUT . I've set the DB credentials as firebase config and even successfully verified the function is able to read the config and get values.

Please let me know do I have to configure RDS security in way that let's firebase function call the DB

Comment: I am not familiar with AWS Relational Database Service but you can follow [this blog](https://blog.devgenius.io/firebase-cloud-functions-integration-with-aws-rds-database-947a383e2e0c) where it is mentioned how to integrate Firebase Functions with AWS RDS.